# how do I access the value in my database using php session?

Tags: php, session

[I am trying to access the class accountPass][1]

```
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['login']))
{
header("location:login.php");
}
```

`include_once '../controller/controller.php';`

```
include_once '../controller/Validation.php';

$account = new account();
$validation = new Validation();

$id = $_SESSION['user.id'];
$query = "SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user.id = '$id'";
$res = $account->accountPass($query);
```

[But I don`t seem to understand why the result is false here.][2]

```
public function accountPass($query)
    {
        $result = $this->connection->query($query);
        if ($result == false) 
        {
            echo 'Error: Cannot execute accountPass';
            return false;       
        } 
        if ($result->num_rows > 0) 
        {
            $row = $result->fetch_assoc();
        }
        return $row;

    }
```

Comment: Update your post with the actual formatted code samples, do not post images of your code.  Based on your code samples and the limited information you've provided, mvc is too wide of a concept for us to know what connection is or why this is failing.

Comment: Don't add images instead of code.

Comment: What debugging have you done? What is the value of `$id`? Do you really have a column named `user.id`? Where is `$this->connection` set in the `account` class? Have you confirmed that it is connecting correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You need to verify that the query returns a row by testing it with a known value. Based on a quick test in MySQL, a column named `user.id` is invalid when queried without back ticks around it. (Assuming you're using MySQL or similar)

```
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE user.id = '1'; -- fails
SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE `user.id` = '1'; -- works
```

Using periods in column names is not recommended for this reason. If you are joining tables with aliases, the alias designator is followed by a period then the column name. As an example:

```
SELECT a.user, r.role FROM accounts AS a LEFT JOIN roles as r ... WHERE a.user = 1001;
```

(above query is NOT complete)

Get `user` column from the `accounts` table and the `role` column from the `roles` table.